# Tableau swap chart in dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I expected to use a box and parameter control to show different worksheets in the dashboard. I made sure that I put the displayed chart at first, the hided charts as followed, and show parameter control, but it did not show the control. How can I solve that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7MEg.png)

Comment: When one graph is selected the other graph must not have data. Use a container for the graphs and use a calculated field to make that nulling of the data happen.

Comment: Also your chart can't have a title. The worksheet won't collapse if it contains anything, including a title.